# Prononciation du mot « Laguiole »

Tags: prononciation, phonétique, noms-propres, étymologie

Bonjour. Le mot « Laguiole » se prononce « layol ». Comment cela se fait-il ? Existe-t-il d'autres exemples de mots dans lesquels la séquence « gu » se prononce comme un Y ?

**Ajout :** La prononciation « layol » est indiquée à la page 446 du dictionnaire « L'officiel du jeu Scrabble », édition 2011-2012, édité par Larousse.

Comment: J'ai toujours entendu prononcer le **gu**.

Comment: @Fractaliste Selon mes sources, prononcer le **gu** est une erreur !

Comment: @Fractaliste Toi, je parie que tu n'es jamais allé à Laguiole. ;) Ils ne plaisantent pas avec la prononciation.

Comment: Un autre exemple, dans la même région: Labruguière à côté de Castres, qui se prononce comme La Bruyère.

Comment: Peut-être que la prononciation du nom de famille "De Broglie" [dəbʁɔj] est à classer dans la même catégorie ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Le couteau comme le fromage viennent du nom de la [ville](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguiole_%28Aveyron%29), qui se situe dans l'[Aveyron](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aveyron_%28d%C3%A9partement%29), au sud du Massif Central, en [pays d'oc](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occitanie).

L'article de Wikipédia donne une référence pour la prononciation : Jean-Marie Pierret, *Phonétique historique du français et notions de phonétique générale*. Pierret [décrit](http://books.google.fr/books?hl=fr&id=mP4JUXoFLBoC&q=Laguiole#v=snippet&q=Laguiole&f=false) parle d'« archaïsme ».

Le [nom de la ville](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguiole_%28Aveyron%29#Toponymie) vient de l'occitant *la glèiòla*. La [prononciation de l'occitan](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prononciation_de_l%27occitan) varie suivant les régions, mais je ne trouve pas de référence qui donnerait une prononciation autre que [gl] ou [ɣl] (c'est-à-dire avec une [variante fricative du G](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/API_%C9%A3)) pour la graphie `gl`. Néanmoins, en italien, `gl` se prononce [[ʎ]](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consonne_spirante_lat%C3%A9rale_palatale_vois%C3%A9e), qui pour des oreilles françaises ressemble à [lj]. Donc si un italien écrit *la glèiòla*, un français entend « la-ié-io-la ». Même s'il n'y a pas forcément de lien direct avec l'italien (Laguiole est loin de l'Italie et plus près de la Catalogne), cela montre une certaine fluidité entre les prononciations [gl], [ʎ] et [lj].

Il s'agit d'un nom propre, dont comme beaucoup d'autres l'orthographe et la prononciation ont eu une histoire un peu différente. Ce phénomène est plus rare dans les noms communs, dont [l'orthographe a été normalisée](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographe_du_fran%C3%A7ais#Histoire) au 17<sup>e</sup> siècle. Je ne vois pas de mot autre qu'un nom propre qui aurait cette même particularité.

Comment: Dans beaucoup d'endroits en Languedoc (je ne connais pas précisément les parlers des autres régions), on « avale » le « gu » entre un *i* et une autre voyelle, c'est notamment le cas du Lauraguais d'où je viens. Par exemple on prononce « *aia* » (au lieu de *aiga*) ou encore « *laiar* » (au lieu de *laguiar*).

Comment: @Hulothe Similaire au Québec, dans un parler très relâché qui tend à disparaître aujourd'hui, on entendait par exemple «fatiyé» pour «fatigué», «tiye» pour «tigre» ou «mèye» pour «maigre».

Answer (score 2):

Au Québec, à un niveau très familier, on entend couramment la prononciation "yeule" pour "gueule" (ex. "Ferme ta yeule!" "Je te casse la yeule!" Rien de très édifiant, mais intéressant néanmoins, quand on sait que les premiers Français d'Amérique venaient du nord de la France.

Comment: On sent bien que la prononciation d'un "g" relaché peut être assez proche d'un "y".

Answer (score 1):

Laguiole est un nom propre (c'est une commune du département de l'Aveyron), donc à toujours écrire avec une capitale. Je ne connais aucun mot de la langue française (autre qu'un nom propre) qui se prononce ainsi.

*EDIT:* Je ne connais pas l'occitan, mais la prononciation vient peut-être du nom occitan de la ville (cf. [Wikipedia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguiole_%28Aveyron%29)).

Comment: Je prononce le nom de fromage ainsi ; pour les couteaux, je ne suis pas sûr.

Answer (score 0):

Ma famille aveyronnaise prononce Laguiole (gui)

Comment: Bienvenue sur French Language SE, Flo.  Est-ce qu'il y a d'autres renseignements ? Voici le [tour] et le centre [help].