# Prononcer ge et gue

Tags: prononciation

Évidemment, je connais les règles de prononciation du g suivi par une voyelle.

Existe-t-il des exceptions ?

C'est-à-dire, y a-t-il des mots où *gui* se prononce comme *gi* (ou l'inverse), *gue* comme *ge*, etc. ?

Comment: Une question connexe: [Prononciation du mot « Laguiole »](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8991/prononciation-du-mot-laguiole). Je pense que peut-être il y a des noms propres d'origine allemande avec /g/ dans "gi" ou "ge".

Comment: Je pense qu'il faut dissocier noms communs (soumis aux regles) et noms propres (dont la prononciation est deformees pour de multiples raisons) qui n'ont pas qu'une prononciation d'origine "historique" pour ainsi dire.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Les emprunts à l'allemand en *ge-* se prononcent avec /g/ et non /ʒ/ :

- la théorie de la Gestalt
- la gestapo

Les noms propres allemands :

- Hegel
- Schwarzenegger

Il y en a certainement bien d'autres.

Attention, *geiger* dans le *compteur geiger* se prononce /ʒeʒɛʀ/ alors qu'il a été inventé par le physicien Hans Geiger /gaɪ̯gɐ/.

Gilgamesh se prononce /ɡilɡamɛʃ/.

*gui* je crois ne se prononce jamais /ʒi/, le plus souvent /gi/, parfois /gɥi/ comme dans aiguille /ɛgɥij/.  Les deux prononciations sont possibles dans *Guise* pour les ducs de Guise même si /giz/ tend à supplanter la prononciation traditionnelle en /gɥiz/

Pour rester dans les langues voisines du français auxquelles il a emprunté, le *gi* italien est ou bien francisé en /ʒi/ ou /ʒj/, si l'emprunt est ancien ou bien acclimaté, ou bien prononcé à l'italienne, /dʒ/ ou /dʒi/, et souvent mal /dʒj/ :

- l'adagio /adaʒjo/, italien /a'da:dʒo/, du 21ème concerto pour piano de Mozart
- Gino Cervi (le maire communiste adversaire de Fernandel dans les *Don Camillo*) /ʒinosɛʀvi/, italien /'dʒi:no  'ʧɛrvi/
- Roberto Baggio (le pénalty raté de la finale de 94) /badʒjo/ ou /baʒjo/, italien /'badʒ:o/

J'arrête là, il y aurait une thèse à faire sur la manière dont les noms étrangers sont écorchés en français.

Comment: Tout à fait juste, je n'avais pas *gestapo* en tête, comme ajout à la dernière ligne avec des prononciations différentes, on pourrait ajouter *Guatemala* ainsi que *guacamole*.

Comment: Schwarzenegger n'est pas forcément un bon exemple. Y a-t-il des règles de prononciation de 'gg' suivi d'une voyelle en français ?

Comment: This answer does not stress enough that it is never true for common names. The only "exceptions" you are mentioning are always a word (still written with a capital) coming from a German name and written as proper nouns, such as e.g. "compteur Geiger".

Comment: @MathieuBouville Pourquoi n'est-ce pas un bon exemple? En français, le deuxième **g** de la suite **gg** se prononce bien comme un **j** comme dans *suggérer* et ses multiples dérivés. Les mots étrangers adoptés en français contenant **gg** ont le plus souvent (et peut-être toujours) une prononciation distincte comme *toboggan* ou *joggeur*.

Comment: D'autres mots où *g* garde un son dur: *yogi*, *kugelhof*, *hamburger*, *boggie*, *groggy*, *call girl*, *reggae*.

Comment: @jlliagre D'accord, mais en fait, tu ne respectes que la regle, a savoir, noms communs suivant les regles, sauf noms (souvent propres) d'origine etrangere. Ce qui parait logique vu la differenciation entre ces langues et le francais. On peut faire le meme constat de "deformation de prononciation" des mots empruntes au francais dans d'autres langues.

Comment: @Paradox Plutôt qu'étranger/français, mieux vaut évoquer ici les langues romanes qui placent un *u* après le *g* et avant *i* ou *e* pour préserver le son dur (parfois un *h* comme dans ghetto et spaghetti) et les langues germaniques qui n'ont pas besoin de cette convention. À ce propos, une prononciation incorrecte parfois entendue en France est celle du prénom espagnol *Miguel* prononcé "migouèl" /miguɛl/ au lieu de /migɛl/ ou mieux /migel/.

Comment: @jlliagre J'allais parler des directions differentes prises notamment au sein des langues indo-europeennes, ce qui serait plus precis, mais beaucoup moins accessible. Par consequent, quite a prendre un raccourci, je prefere prendre une approche plus "restrictive" pour eviter les erreurs, plutot que qu'etaler un catalogue d'exemples tres specifiques, difficile a exploiter.